# CustomCell content not updated after fetchRequest with changed CoreData values

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchrequest, custom-cell

I must be missing something simple but cannot identify what it is.  BASIC and FORTRAN sure seemed a lot easier... just not as cool as this stuff is.

App is to display & sort flashcards stored in CoreData based on a predicate.  After selecting options which modify the predicate, a UITableView is displayed listing the cards meeting the criteria in abbreviated form.  Selecting a card row segues to a 2nd view controller with identical predicate setup in UITableView only more content shown & "Skill Level" can be modified and saved via CoreData on this 2nd view controller.  Depending on the fetchRequest predicate, a card may no longer match the criteria and might be excluded from a subsequent fetchRequest.  This all seems to function properly.

Selecting "Back" returns to the 1st UITableView controller from the 2nd, via an unwind segue.  At this point, the fetchRequest is again executed along with a tableview.reloadData().  On return, flashcards sort in the proper order based on any changes. Flashcards that no longer meet the predicate criteria are properly excluded from the table.

The problem is this - the custom cell contents do not reflect any changes made (stars graphic doesn't change and numeric value of the Skill Level doesn't change when printed from the tableView).  TableView sorts correctly and doesn't include items it shouldn't which seems to indicate the updated information was saved and has somehow been taken into consideration by the tableView. TableView just doesn't show it on the screen.

If I select "Back" again, returning to the "Home" or initial viewController & immediately segue to it again the tableView displays properly.

I've tried placing tableView.reloadData() in various locations(with and without .self), moving the fetch & reloads in and out of DispatchQueue.main.async. Tried replacing the control in the custom cell with images but that didn't work either.  Can't seem to find anything quite like it on stack overflow or elsewhere on internet.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Custom Cell:

```
import UIKit
class CardsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var difficultyImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var knowItControl: KnowItControl!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

UnwindFromSegue:

```
@IBAction func unwindToCardsTableViewController(sender: UIStoryboardSegue) {   
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            // RELOAD THE FLASHCARDS FOR TABLEVIEW
            do {
                try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Fetching error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
            print("\n UNWIND - About to reload table")
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        print("UNWIND SEGUE from DetailedCardsView")
        // Considered giving up and just dumping back to Main Screen.
        // dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Assembling the tableView using extensions in the tableViewController

```
// MARK: - ConfigureCardsTableViewCell
extension CardsTableViewController {

    func configure(cell: UITableViewCell, for indexPath: IndexPath) {
       guard let cell = cell as? CardsTableViewCell else { return }

        let flashCards = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath)
        cell.knowItControl.rating = Int(flashCards.cardKnowIt)
        cell.questionLabel.text = flashCards.cardQuestion

        // * * *  ASSIGN THE IMAGE BASED ON THE levelDifficulty * * *
        switch flashCards.levelDifficulty {
        case "e"?:
            cell.difficultyImageView.image = UIImage(named: "activeLetterE")
        case "g"?:
            cell.difficultyImageView.image = UIImage(named: "activeLetterG")
        case "m"?:
            cell.difficultyImageView.image = UIImage(named: "activeLetterM")
        default:
            cell.difficultyImageView.image = UIImage(named: "activeLetterE")
        }
        //  *************************  END OF ASSIGN IMAGE ****************************************
        print("assembling cell \(indexPath.row) *** knowIt - \(Int(flashCards.cardKnowIt))")  // Observe what is going on, see if value was updated (it's not).
        }
}


// * * * *    T A B L E V I E W     D A T A S O U R C E  * * * *
// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource
extension CardsTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    // * * *   C O N F I G U R E    T H E   C E L L   V I A    A   C A L L   * * *
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCellReuse", for: indexPath)
        configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath)
        print("   Configuring cell \(indexPath)")   // Observe what is going on.
        return cell
        }
 // general tableView functions for number of rows, sections, etc.   
}
```

The viewController also contains the generic NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate which I believe accurately matches all the examples I've come across.

Screen shots shown here.
1 - Initial load of 1st tableView from "Home" page properly displays content.
2 - Segued to 2nd tableView where changes were made and saved to CoreData.
3 - Returned to 1st tableView using unwind.  Cells are sorted correctly but don't contain updated values.
4 - Left 1st tableView via Back and immediately loaded it again and the screen properly displays content.  Just wish it did it without having to "go home & return".
[image: 1st tableView displaying cards meeting criteria]

[image: 2nd tableView after segue from 1st, changing the Skill Level & saving it]

[image: Returned to 1st tableView where items are properly sorted, but cells unchanged.]

[image: Exit 1st tableView via "Back" & re-load. All appears as it should.]

NSFetched Results Controller Delegate:

```
// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
extension CardsTableViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        print("\n **** tableView.beganUpdates called")
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
        case .update:
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! CardsTableViewCell
            configure(cell: cell, for: indexPath!)
            print("case .update was called.")
        case .move:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
        print("\n **** tableView.endUpdates called")
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {

        let indexSet = IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex)

        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(indexSet, with: .automatic)
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: These images are really huge.  I'll reduce them if someone will tell me how.

Comment: Did you implement NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate properly? E.g `controller(_:didChange:at:for:newIndexPath:)`

Comment: I have the code shown above. It is also in the 2nd viewController and executes in the 2nd viewController when a change is made.  The changes have already been saved in the 2nd viewController before it returns to the 1st one.

Comment: Are you sure `didChanged` delegates called properly? Make sure delegate has been setup properly and unwind segue fired on back button action. Try to put some break points for debugging.

Comment: If I change an object in the unwind, just as a test, the "beginUpdate", "case .update", and "endUpdates" all kick in.  Only test object's cell is updated and the others that changed within the 2nd view controller are not updated.  It appears to only reflect to changes made in its' own viewController.  Can the fetchRequest be forced to reload from CoreData like it does when the 1st viewController is loaded the first time?

Comment: Decided to change the way the App works and just pass the data back to the 1st ViewController and save it on that view.  Works fine, just thought it would be smoother to not pop back and forth to update values.